# Amine addition to nitro group

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, nitro-compounds, amines

What is the mechanisms of this reaction? How feasible is this reaction? Can it happen under relatively mild conditions if it is intermolecular?

[image]

Comment: It's actually a hydrazine that adds to the nitro group. Usually one wouldn't bother to isolate the nitrosubstituted phenyl hydrazine and instead react 2-nitrochlorobenze with aqueous hydrazine under alkaline conditions.

Comment: That would just make a nucleophilic aromatic substitution.

Comment: Exactly - for the first step.  But would it stop there or  rather continue to furnish HOBt?

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info, but I am far more interested in the mechanism of the attached reaction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A reasonable mechanism for the transformation is shown below. Since this is under basic conditions, I've written a mechanism that avoids cationic intermediates. Deprotonating the hydrazine gives a very nucleophilic nitrogen that can attack the nitro group. Proton transfer gives a nitrogen anion, which can kick out hydroxide. Two additional proton transfer steps lead to the product, HOBt.

[image: Proposed mechanism]

A SciFinder search didn't reveal any examples of the intermolecular variant of this reaction, although I didn't find this exact intramolecular reaction either.